# How do you find the algorithmic complexity of code fragements?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I don't know what the procedure of this would be. How do I think of this, how do I determine what the big-O will be? What is the process to solving?

Example1:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for (j = 1; j <= n*3; j++)
    System.out.println("Apple");
```

Example2:

```
for (i = 1; i < n*n*n; i *=n) 
    System.out.println("Banana");
```

Thank you

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194433/is-this-a-proper-rule-for-identifying-the-big-o-notation-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you count the loops. If there is no loop, it is O constant, if there is one it is O(N) if there are two nested loops it is O(N squared) and if there are three it is O(N cubed).

However that's only the short answer. You can also have loops which reduce an input by half on each iteration, so thats a log N term. And you can have pathological brute force functions which try every possibility, these are non-polynomial. Usually they are written to make heavy use of recursion and the problem is hardly chipped away at on each recursive step.

Be aware that library functions are often not O constant, and that has to be factored in.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O measures efficiency. So say you were to loop through an array of size n and say n is 2,000. O(n) would signify that your algorithm for solving this is doing WORST CASE 2,000 total calculations. O is always the worst case scenario for your algorithm. There are other notation used for best case. You also have Ω(n) and Θ(n).

Check this out to kind of get an idea of the difference in efficiency: 
http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Informally:

"T(n)T(n)T(n) is O(f(n))O(f(n))O(f(n))" basically means that f(n)f(n)f(n) describes the **upper bound** for T(n)T(n)T(n)

"T(n)T(n)T(n) is Ω(f(n))\Omega(f(n))Ω(f(n))" basically means that f(n)f(n)f(n) describes the **lower bound** for T(n)T(n)T(n)

"T(n)T(n)T(n) is Θ(f(n))\Theta(f(n))Θ(f(n))" basically means that f(n)f(n)f(n) describes the **exact bound** for T(n)T(n)T(n)

A good way to approach this for simple situations is to plug a couple of easy numbers in for n and see what happens. So say n is size 10:

in example 1:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++) //loop through this n times
  for (j = 1; j <= n*3; j++) for each of those n times, loop through 3*n times
    System.out.println("Apple"); //negligible time (O(1))
```

If it were just the outside loop, it would be O(n). However, since you add the inside loop, you get O(N^2) because although your input is (say) 10, you're doing 300 (30 prints for each of the 10; 30*10) operations. 3* O(N^2) but we generally leave the 3 out so O(n^2). Most nested for loops **where you aren't modifying by n** are O(n^2).

If it's easier you can visualize it as the polynomial 3n * n = 3n^2 worst case.

I'll let you try the next one... hint in the bold statement above.